# Will upgrading iPhone 3GS from 4.3.5 -> 5.0 work?

Tags: iphone, ios5, ios6, ios4, upgrade

I'm looking at upgrading my development iPhone 3GS from iOS4.3.5 to iOS5. Now that Apple even rejects apps that use the older SDK and contain an iPhone 5 launch image, I see no need to keep my iPhone 3GS on iOS4.

Even though the latest s/w for iPhone 3GS is iOS6, will an upgrade to iOS5 be successful through the server verification. I ask because I tried to restore in a similar situation previously on a different device (and different iOS versions) but it wouldn't let me so I had to upgrade to the latest compatible version of iOS.

Success/failure stories would be much appreciated.

Thanks,
James

PS. this may not be a techy question, but as a community of developers, this seems to be the best place to ask!

Comment: don't do it! You might eventually need hardware running the old OS and then you are out of luck (unless you want to jailbreak.) Buy new hardware... :- ( I've just bought a bunch of old hardware on ebay just because I HAD upgraded!

Comment: Thanks @PaulCezanne, due to Apple not allowing you to support iOS4 and the iPhone 5 simultaneously, there is no point (in my opinion) having a device < iOS 5

Comment: I tell all my clients that if they want to support iOS4 it is going to have to cost them quite a lot. So far, they have all backed down.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apple no longer signs iOS5 meaning that you can't restore to iOS5 unless you have previously saved the SHSH blobs either in Cydia or with a tool such as [TinyUmbrella](http://thefirmwareumbrella.blogspot.nl/).

See Explained: [SHSH Blobs](http://blog.secretss.com/iphone-stuff/explained-shsh-blobs/)

Comment: unfortunately I think this answer is correct as it was the one I was expecting. Thanks for your confirmation